# Thanks for the Slider. But How to Add Custom Text and logs in center of each slide.? thanks

Tags: jquery, slider

i came across this amazing slider and simply loved it. Yet the slider doesn't feature auto play or loop.
Could you help me with that.
I tried using j Query but i am quite confused.
your help is deeply appreciated.
[**Check out the Slider here**](https://codepen.io/mrspok407/pen/bwLwvL/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
const $cont = $('.cont');
const $slider = $('.slider');
const $nav = $('.nav');
const winW = $(window).width();
const animSpd = 750; // Change also in CSS
const distOfLetGo = winW * 0.2;
let curSlide = 1;
let animation = false;
let autoScrollVar = true;
let diff = 0;
```

Sample here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For autoplay, add a `setInterval` function to run `navigateRight()`, every e.g. 2s:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    if (animation) return;
    navigateRight();
}, 2000);
```

For looping, change `navigateLeft()`, `navigateRight()` and `bullets()` functions to indicate what to do when they reach the end, e.g.:

```js
if (curSlide >= numOfCities) {
    curSlide = 0;
};
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/esjdpnuf/)

Comment: Hey i have one thing that is quite confusing. How can i add a div with text in centre like an overlay for all slides? thanks

Comment: @Ben [here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/o5szt6ge/) of how you can do that.